# Including 'pythonhighlight' package creates error

Tags: pdftex, listings, python

I would like to include the 'pythonhighlight' package in an book I'm writing. This is the code that creates the included error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
eta = 0.1 # Learning rate
n_iterations = 1000
n = 100

theta = np.random.randn(2,1) # Random initialization

for iteration in range(n_iterations):
    gradients = 2/n * X_b.T.dot(b.dot(theta) - y)
    theta = theta - eta * gradients

\end{python}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.5 \begin{python}

? X
No pages of output.
```

I have researched this error and the usual answer is to delete the aux files. That solution is not working here.

Comment: Your example runs fine on my system, without any errors. Maybe it is a version problem, which version of `pythonhighlight` and `listings` do you use, and which version of `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Marijn : Thanks for your answer. Versions are: `pythonhighlight` - No version number, Dated 2/10/2017; `Listings` version - 1.8d; `pdfLatex` version - 3.1415.

Comment: On my system `listings` is older (1.6), the rest is the same. You could try to copy the listing style defined in the source code of `pythonhighlight` and use that with `listings` directly, reducing the settings line by line until it starts working. That may help you to find the exact source of the error, which in turn might lead to finding a solution.

Comment: @Marijn:  Great answer, but I wouldn't have a clue of how to go about messing around with the `listings` code. May I bother you with a hint or two? Thanks.

Comment: What I mean was: remove `\usepackage{pythonhighlight}` from your test document, take the source code from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythonhighlight/pythonhighlight.sty, copy that code (except for the needstexformat and providespackage lines) to your test document at the position where `\usepackage{pythonhighlight}` used to be, verify if it still fails, then start removing lines from the style definition of `\lstdefinestyle{mypython}` until the code no longer fails.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Marijn. I followed it and discovered that a line that went ```basicstyle=\ttfamily,\footnotesize,%\setstretch{.5},``` I corrected it to ```basicstyle=\ttfamily,%\footnotesize,%\setstretch{.5},``` and that solved the problem. Now, can anybody explain why this worked? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe your class file or some package modifies `\footnotesize` in such a way that it breaks `listings` - it's hard to say for sure without seeing the full code. But good that you managed to solve it :)